# White box is Not appearing on my screen

Tags: java

I am following a long this tutorial on how to make a game in java. Im pretty sure ive typed all the code exactly. The goal is just to display a white box on the screen to act as the player, but for some reason the white box is not showing up I will post all the classes below.

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9;
public static boolean running = false;
Thread thread;

private Handler handler;
public Game(){
    new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT, "This Is My Game", this);
    handler = new Handler();

    handler.addObject(new Player(100,100, ID.Player));

}

public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;

}

public synchronized void stop(){
        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if(running){
            render();
        frames++;
        }

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Fps: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }

    }
    stop();
}

public void tick(){
    handler.tick();

}

public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    handler.render(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game();

}

}


public class Player extends GameObject {

    public Player(int x, int y,ID id) {
        super(x, y, id);
    }


    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
    }



}





public abstract class GameObject {
    protected int x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected int velX, velY;


    public GameObject(int x,int y,ID id){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;

    }
}




public class Handler {
    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size();i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size();i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }

    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){

        this.object.remove(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anybody calling the `Game.start()` method that starts the thread. Try:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game().start();
}
```

Comment: so that kind of works. instead of the rectangle not displaying it is now just blinking kind of. Different parts of the square that im drawing are displaying randomly then disappearing @beosign thanks for the help though